# How can I stop mediaplayer from playing over itself?

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, media

I have an application in which the user can click a button and start listening to a given track (it is just one long track of a whole album, they can only play and pause).

The problem is that if you start playing the music, go to the second activity and then return to the homepage, you now have the option to press play on the music (even though it is still playing). When you then press play, it starts the track again, over the top of the one which is already playing.

To clarify, I want the music to play over all of the activity, but when you go back to the homepage I want the media player to realise that it is still playing the track and allow the user to pause/play as they wish.

Here is the code for the first activity, the second activity is 'Behind The Scenes':

```
package alexgreene.byprocessofimagination;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;

import static alexgreene.byprocessofimagination.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    ImageButton play, bts, readMore;
    int startTime = 4250;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
        readMore = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibReadMore);
        bts = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibBackgroundFalling);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.eusa);
        mp.seekTo(startTime);

        bts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     BehindTheScenes.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_headphones);
                } else {
                    play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause_headphones);
                    mp.start();
                }
            }
        });

        readMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                    settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup,     null));
                settingsDialog.show();

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play the media using service instead of activity.

Follow this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html for detailed info

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).